# String Boot test failed

Tags: java, spring, testing

Here is the GitHub repo of my Spring Boot application that I have trouble with: [click me](https://github.com/HanYuanHsu/shepherd-money/tree/master).

I want to test the `createUser` method:

```
    /**
     * creates a user entity with information given in the payload, stores the user entity in the database, and
     * return 200 ok response with the id of the saved user
     *
     * @param payload user's information
     * @return 200 ok response with the id of the saved user
     */
    @PutMapping("/user") // handles PUT requests
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> createUser(@RequestBody CreateUserPayload payload) {
        // create a user entity with information given in the payload
        User newUser = new User(payload.getName(), payload.getEmail());

        // store the user entity in the database
        User savedUser = this.userRepository.save(newUser);

        // create a ResponseEntity with http status 'ok'
        // and return it with the id of the saved user
        return ResponseEntity.ok(savedUser.getId());
    }
```

The payload class looks like:

```
@Data
public class CreateUserPayload {

    private String name;

    private String email;
}
```

The `User` class looks like:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "MyUser")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    // TODO: User's credit card
    // HINT: A user can have one or more, or none at all. We want to be able to query credit cards by user
    //       and user by a credit card.
    private Set<Integer> creditCards = new HashSet<Integer>();

    /**
     * adds a credit card to this user
     * @param cardId
     */
    public void addCreditCard(int cardId) {
        creditCards.add(cardId);
    }


    public User(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    /*
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

     */
}
```

Here is the test code. The user repository `ur` should call the save method and receive the name "John" and the email "john@example.org":

```
 @Test
    public void shouldCreateUser() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(put("/user")
                        .content("{\"name\": \"John\", \"email\": \"john@example.org\"}")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk()
                );

        verify(ur).save(argThat(user -> user.getName().equals("John") &&
                user.getEmail().equals("john@example.org")));
    }
```

However, this test didn't pass, and I got the following test result:

```
00:09:12.363 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [InterviewProjectApplicationTests]: using SpringBootContextLoader
00:09:12.403 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.shepherdmoney.interviewproject.InterviewProjectApplicationTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
00:09:12.408 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.shepherdmoney.interviewproject.InterviewProjectApplicationTests]: InterviewProjectApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
00:09:12.768 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using ContextCustomizers for test class [InterviewProjectApplicationTests]: [DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer, PropertyMappingContextCustomizer, Customizer, ImportsContextCustomizer, ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer, DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer, MockitoContextCustomizer, TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer]
00:09:13.353 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/mnt/c/Users/a0306/shepherd-money/build/classes/java/main/com/shepherdmoney/interviewproject/InterviewProjectApplication.class]
00:09:13.364 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.shepherdmoney.interviewproject.InterviewProjectApplication for test class com.shepherdmoney.interviewproject.InterviewProjectApplicationTests
00:09:14.623 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners for test class [InterviewProjectApplicationTests]: [ServletTestExecutionListener, DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, MockitoTestExecutionListener, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, TransactionalTestExecutionListener, SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, EventPublishingTestExecutionListener, RestDocsTestExecutionListener, MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, WebDriverTestExecutionListener, MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, ResetMocksTestExecutionListener]
00:09:14.637 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: class [InterviewProjectApplicationTests], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.2)

00:09:17.460 INFO  --- [    Test worker]   c.s.i.InterviewProjectApplicationTests:51  : Starting InterviewProjectApplicationTests using Java 17.0.8 with PID 1255 (started by hankevin in /mnt/c/Users/a0306/shepherd-money)
00:09:17.472 INFO  --- [    Test worker]   c.s.i.InterviewProjectApplicationTests:630 : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
00:09:21.482 INFO  --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:291 : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
00:09:21.483 INFO  --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:138 : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
00:09:21.925 INFO  --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:208 : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 380 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
00:09:23.328 INFO  --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:291 : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
00:09:23.328 INFO  --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:138 : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
00:09:23.474 INFO  --- [    Test worker] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport:320 : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.shepherdmoney.interviewproject.repository.CreditCardRepository; If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
00:09:23.475 INFO  --- [    Test worker] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport:320 : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.shepherdmoney.interviewproject.repository.UserRepository; If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
00:09:23.475 INFO  --- [    Test worker] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate:208 : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 146 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
00:09:26.214 INFO  --- [    Test worker] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker:409 : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
00:09:26.373 INFO  --- [    Test worker] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping:239 : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
00:09:27.589 INFO  --- [    Test worker]  o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper:31  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
00:09:28.269 INFO  --- [    Test worker]                    org.hibernate.Version:44  : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.6.Final
00:09:30.776 WARN  --- [    Test worker]            org.hibernate.orm.deprecation:626 : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
00:09:32.569 INFO  --- [    Test worker]       com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:110 : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
00:09:35.043 INFO  --- [    Test worker]        com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:565 : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:file:~/database user=SA
00:09:35.059 INFO  --- [    Test worker]       com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:123 : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
00:09:35.303 INFO  --- [    Test worker]                              SQL dialect:66  : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
00:09:43.571 WARN  --- [    Test worker]     o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl:27  : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table if exists credit_card add column user integer not null" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table if exists credit_card add column user integer not null" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:587)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:608)
    at 
    ... common frames omitted
00:09:43.701 INFO  --- [    Test worker]       o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator:51  : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
00:09:43.842 INFO  --- [    Test worker] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:437 : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
00:09:46.523 WARN  --- [    Test worker] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration:227 : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
00:09:50.524 INFO  --- [    Test worker]    o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration:88  : H2 console available at '/h2-ui'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:file:~/database'
00:09:50.862 INFO  --- [    Test worker] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext:435 : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
00:09:50.862 INFO  --- [    Test worker]  o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet:532 : Initializing Servlet ''
00:09:50.865 INFO  --- [    Test worker]  o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet:554 : Completed initialization in 0 ms
00:09:50.926 INFO  --- [    Test worker]   c.s.i.InterviewProjectApplicationTests:57  : Started InterviewProjectApplicationTests in 35.689 seconds (process running for 43.199)

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = PUT
      Request URI = /user
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"45"]
             Body = {"name": "John", "email": "john@example.org"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.shepherdmoney.interviewproject.controller.UserController
           Method = com.shepherdmoney.interviewproject.controller.UserController#createUser(CreateUserPayload)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = 302
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Can somebody interpret this result? I do not know where the problem is. Much appreciated.

Update: actually, when I start the server by running `./gradlew bootRun`, I get the following error message:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table if exists credit_card add column user integer not null" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:587)
        at ... omitted
```

According to the phrase "alter table if exists credit_card add column user integer not null", I am guessing this is a problem related to the database. But I don't know anything further...

Update 2: according to @WLefever, I changed `user` to `userId`. But the method still didn't pass the test. The report I got was shorter though. It looks like:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = PUT
      Request URI = /user
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"45"]
             Body = {"name": "John", "email": "john@example.org"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.shepherdmoney.interviewproject.controller.UserController
           Method = com.shepherdmoney.interviewproject.controller.UserController#createUser(CreateUserPayload)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = 452
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Comment: are you sure this is working outside the test? in order for jackson to be able to deserialize the request body, the DTO object must have no args constructor (I see you work with lombok so @NoArgsConstructor)

Comment: @LiorDerei yes, when I run `curl -X PUT -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "John", "email": "john@example.com"}' http://localhost:8080/user`, I do get 200 ok response. Then I run `curl http://localhost:8080/users` and the name and the email did appear.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `CreditCard` contains a field having the same name as a reserved keyword *user*.

```
public class CreditCard {
...

    private int user; // the id of the user
}
```

You should change to `userId` for example.

```
public class CreditCard {
...

    private int userId; // the id of the user
}
```